# How can use RegEx to catch the next line that follows a specific string in VBA (Outlook)?

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

I need to take the following line in a string included in the text body of an email.

Comment: Currently, you are not asking a question. Please add one so people can try to help you. Try to be clear where the problem lies and spell out any error messages you might encounter.

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by "catch": Do you want to simply match the pattern? Do you want to capture the next line in a capture group to subsequently process it? You might want to include an example of how the input looks and what part you want to match/capture.

Comment: Also relevant is which body?  Locating strings in the Html body will probably be much more difficult than locating them in the text body.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your replies, really apreciate it.

Comment: There are those who can apply regex in VBA but cannot work out a valid "myString". As previously requested " You might want to include an example of how the input looks".

Comment: I just realized something. If the current edit is an answer then revert back to a question and put the answer into an answer post.

Comment: You have confirmed, as I suspected, you are using the text body (.Body) and not the Html Body (.HtmlBody).  I believe text bodies are created by Outlook since every email I have examined has a text version of the Html body and these text versions are total consistent in their structure.  To create a text body: replace any existing white space with a single space, insert CRLFCRLF at the end of every block element and table cell and then delete all Html tags.  That is why, the text body is composed of lines.

Comment: Okay thank You. Actually the use of text body is usefull for me as it is composed of lines.

Comment: I edited the question but then realized you inteded to have it this way and answered your own question. Please consider adding more information to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Edit : Here is what I've found and did and that seems to work. This code will 
 check if a specific string exists and You can do something with the line that 
 follows it.

```
 Function TestRegExp(myString As String)

'Create objects.
Dim objRegExp As RegExp
Dim objMatch As Match
Dim colMatches   As MatchCollection
Dim RetStr As String
Dim result As String


' Create a regular expression object.
Set objRegExp = New RegExp

'Set the pattern by using the Pattern property.
objRegExp.Pattern = "Order[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)"

' Set Case Insensitivity.
objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True

'Set global applicability.
objRegExp.Global = True

'Test whether the String can be compared.
If (objRegExp.Test(myString) = True) Then

For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection.
MsgBox objMatch.SubMatches(0)
result = objMatch.SubMatches(0)

Next
End If
End If

TestRegExp = result


End Function
```